# Some trig identities wanted.

Tags: trigonometry

Let $S(x)=\sin^2(x)$ and $C(x)=\cos^2(x)$.
Let $P_i$ be some multivariable polynomial with positive coefficients.

Im looking for trig identities of the form $S(x)S(y)=P_1(S,C)$.
And also $S(x+y)=P_2(S,C)$ and $S(x)S(y)S(z)=P_3(S,C)$

Comment: Disclaimer: Im not sure these identities exist ...

Answer (score 0):

Try and take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Maybe this can helf you

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: No not really. I know those identities already. Usefull to prove identities though.